# Alfresco 5.2.4 in weblogic server

Tags: weblogic12c, alfresco-enterprise

I am getting the following error when trying to install Alfresco 5.2.4 in weblogic 12. I am using all the supported technology stack as per the alfresco documentation. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<Nov 28, 2018 10:13:21,313 PM CST> <Error> <javax.faces> <BEA-000000> <Unable 
to call @PreDestroy annotated methods because no InjectionProvider can be 
found. Does this container implement the Mojarra Injection SPI?> 
<Nov 28, 2018 10:13:21,313 PM CST> <Error> 
<javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config> <BEA-000000> <Critical 
error during deployment: 
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Factory 
'javax.faces.lifecycle.ClientWindowFactory' was not configured properly.
```

Answer (score 2):

I have faced similar issue recently. The following Work Around should fix this error:

Uncomment following lines in /META-INF/weblogic-application.xml

```
<package-name>javax.faces.*</package-name> 
<package-name>javax.faces.application.*</package-name> 
<package-name>javax.faces.component.*</package-name> 
<package-name>javax.faces.context.*</package-name> 
<package-name>javax.faces.convert.*</package-name> 
<package-name>javax.faces.el.*</package-name> 
<package-name>javax.faces.event.*</package-name> 
<package-name>javax.faces.lifecycle.*</package-name> 
<package-name>javax.faces.model.*</package-name> 
<package-name>javax.faces.render.*</package-name> 
<package-name>javax.faces.validator.*</package-name> 
<package-name>javax.faces.webapp.*</package-name>
```